# UITabBarController -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: warning

Tags: ios, ios5, uitabbarcontroller, warnings, lldb

I am getting the following warning from lldb:

> The view controller  returned NO from
>   -shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: for all interface orientations. It should support at least one orientation.

This is a standard UITabBarController, not a subclass and has no categories. Why am I getting this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default implementation of `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` for UITabBarController returns the orientations that is allowed for *all* the tabs.

So, you are either having one view controller (for a tab) that returns NO for all orientations or you are having conflicting orientations (one view which only supports landscape and another that only supports portrait).

Answer (score 0):

It should support at least one orientation, doing a check to see if the orientation is portrait will return yes.
 return toInterFaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait 
should help a lot.

Comment: It isn't a subclass. It is a default Apple made UITabBarController.